# simple_html_dom - get content loading webpage is too long

Tags: php, html, dom, relative-path, simple-html-dom

Iam using simple_html_dom to get webpage but the problem is loading web pages is too long until show message request timeout:

```
$link = "http://stok.jakartagrosir.com/user/ju.prod.php?brand=207&view=";
$html = file_get_html($link);
$table = $htm ->find('table', 0);
echo $table;
```

I thing it because css, js, etc using relative path, I do not know how to outsmart this webpage scrape can loading fast.
can help me please ?

Comment: That page takes forever to load. There's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: I not sure about nothing can do about that, can you give me some reason why ?

Comment: Well I suppose you can contact them and ask them to fix it but other than that, no nothing can be done.